# How to preprocess data for building model

Tags: python, matlab, machine-learning

I have a dataset wherein each column has either a strut/array/integers corresponding to each row. Further the structures or arrays in each cell are of different dimensions. Could anyone please guide me as to how could this data be flattened/ structured so that I could use it to build an SVM model or to use as input data for clustering.

This is a sample of how the data is like:

    `a_data   b_data ........n_data
r1   7.162   [24×1] strut   [6×2]double
r2   0.1945  [361×1] strut  [40×2]double
.
.
.
rn`

[24×1] struct is something like

`732338.705682870    0   'no'
732338.706597222    1   'yes'
732338.707777778    0   'maybe'
732339.525729167    0   'yes'`

I am not sure if I have to standardize/ normalize/ binarize this kind of data and how I can achieve it on this dataset. Any information on this or experiences shared on handling similar data would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well! You need to convert each structure to a vector somehow. Without real data it is impossible to suggest. So, could you put `dput` of your data and something you have tried? Perhaps also programming platform you are trying to use.

Comment: @discipulus My data is very much similar to the sample data I posted. I am trying to work with the data using python libraries but the data is available in a mat file. I tried extracting a few columns that contained only integers and normalized them. But now, I want to be able to work with the whole dataset.

Comment: Another trial was that I just spread out the data as is.. I considered the variables of each strut as the base variables for the model and the result was a few columns - each column had similar/ different dataype as compared to the other and all the columns were of different lengths. Surprisingly, MATLAB was able to build a model using decision trees with Gini index on a few rows of this data.

Comment: Add a `python` tag if you wish the answer to be in `python` or `matlab` tag if you want answer in `matlab`.

Comment: @discipulus Sure, I did that.. thanks!